# GRUB will show only on MANUAL BOOT but not on REBOOT (dual boot windows 8.1 ubuntu 13.10)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 13.10, windows-8

Here's my problem:
I have a dual boot installation of Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 8.1 on my laptop and I get the grub menu only when I shutdown and boot again MANUALLY. If I try to simply reboot from Linux or from Windows, my computer directly loads on Windows.

Isn't that strange? Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `etc/default/grub` and search for the entry `GRUB_TIMEOUT` then set its value to `-1`. This will ensure that the GRUB menu will be shown always and you have to choose which OS to boot from. Then update the grub `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

`sudo gedit /etc/grub/default`
`GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1`
`sudo update-grub`
`sudo reboot`

Comment: i didn't had any `/etc/default/grub` file.What can i do?

Comment: Then I'll do what you state in your answer :) . But you know you should have it

Comment: i provide the solution which may or maynot works.As according to your answer,there was no etc/default/grub file in my pc.

Answer (score 0):

Some systems work better to register grub/shim from inside Windows - for those that keep resetting Windows as default

[Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot)

From Windows:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

https://coderwall.com/p/vfyqkg

UEFI NVRAM boot entries are cached in the BCD store
BCD has 1:1 mappings for some UEFI global variables
Any time {fwbootmgr} is manipulated, NVRAM is automatically updated

Comment: How did you know that the windows installed in UEFI mode?

Comment: Did not for sure. Almost all Windows 8 systems especially laptops,seem to be pre-installed, so must be UEFI and the issue is common for UEFI systems.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. And yes it is UEFI I didn't mention it because I thought it came automatically with all Windows 8 laptops. But after the troubles with grub's installation, I re-installed Ubuntu and it works again with the initial behavior (grub showing only on manual boot). I think I'm going to work with that rather than try another action that might mess things again.

Comment: Then my answer may be wrong as you could be booting Ubuntu in BIOS mode and Windows in UEFI mode?

Comment: Can't say for sure, what I know is that the following command:
 
[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "Session EFI" || echo "Session non-EFI"
 
returns a positive answer (Session EFI).

Another strange thing is that if I boot into Windows and desactivate the fast startup option then it gets worse: Grub doesn't show at all anymore...

Comment: You have to have fast startup off. Otherwise Windows is hibernated. Is secure boot on?  Post this. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info