# dual boot ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8 not working

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi, 14.04

so i installed ubuntu 14.04 on a windows 8 pre-installed hp laptop.

the problem is when i boot the computer it takes me straight to windows and NO grub is shown.

i tried following this: https://askubuntu.com/a/358524/59618 and used boot-repair which threw this error http://paste.ubuntu.com/7295325/

i am completely lost with this eufi stuff, can someone help me with an easy solution to have grub working on this laptop where i can choose Ubuntu or windows 8?

PS: i cant seem to get this working on my hp. i disabled fast startup and secure boot and ran `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and still no Grub :(

the solution that this question was marked as duplicate is not working for me

Comment: Wipe Windows 8, install Ubuntu. Profit.

Comment: @cxdy this is not a solution for me because its not my computer and i am trying to convince someone to start using ubuntu

Comment: It was a joke. But if you want to convince them to use Ubuntu, why not just set up a VM on their computer for them and let them get a feel for it?

Comment: i want to setup dual boot because they are going to start using it (slowly). deleting windows is not an option

Comment: Ah, makes sense.
Take a look at these: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tired-of-windows-8-how-to-dual-boot-windows-ubuntu/ and http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html

Comment: Refer the solution at this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot?rq=1

Comment: i cant seem to get this working on my hp. i disabled fast startup and secure boot and ran `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and still no grub :(

Comment: Ask a new question and include in it a link to the `RESULTS.txt` file that [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) produces or the link that Boot Repair produces. Without that data, any further advice will be guesswork.

Comment: it started working. i didnt do anything, just installed a new anti virus in windows. why is that?

Answer (score -1):

Had same problem after installing Ubuntu 14.04 to dual boot with Windows XP.  Solved by going into Bios and making boot drive the Ubuntu drive.  A restart brought up the grub 2 screen with options for Ubuntu  and  XP.  I've been using this method and so far no problems with either choice.

Comment: im not sure this is the same problem i have.. do you have uefi? do you boot your computer always with a usb pen drive do be able to see grub?

Comment: A Windows XP computer is almost certainly BIOS-based, and so such a solution will *not* apply to the question at hand.