# Windows Boot Loader not letting GRUB be default Loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a HP Laptop which I dual booted with Windows 8 and Linux Ubuntu. After the installation,Windows started automatically without any GRUB menu. However if I pressed <kbd>F9</kbd> at the start I got "Boot Options" where Ubuntu was specified and I could boot into Ubuntu from there. So I searched the forum and found [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot) which explained how to restore the GRUB menu.

However even after trying following command several times I couldn't get the GRUB menu.

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

I even tried using `efibootmgr` to change boot order but it was no god and I couldn't get the GRUB menu as the order was resetted every time I restarted my computer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) and also see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the boot order in your BIOS/UEFI settings?

You can usually get to your BIOS/UEFI settings by pressing <kbd>DEL</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd> right after powering on your PC. Set your HD with Ubuntu or Ubuntu's EFI entry as the first boot option and save your settings.

Your PC will restart and boot using GRUB by default.

Comment: The HD with Ubuntu is Dual booted with Windows 8. There is no such option in BIOS to manipulate EFI entries.

Comment: Does your computer support EFI and do you use the GPT partition table with an EFI partition?

Comment: Yes my Computer supports UEFI and i have used GPT partition tables with EPI partition . However i have installed both Windows 8 and Ubuntu in Legacy BIOS mode.

Comment: If you've disabled EFI support you obviously can't use the EFI files. Could you try to boot in Ubuntu and reinstall GRUB using `sudo install-grub /dev/sda && sudo update-grub`? Replace `/dev/sda` with the hard drive you want to boot from.

Answer (score -1):

go into the UEFI settings. this is done with the `Esc` or `F10` keys on a HP laptop

Move to system configuration and go down to `change boot order` then go to the option with the arrow next to it. when you open the menu it should show all the OS'es accessible in the boot menu. select one and save the changes. you should be booting to that drive whenever it is plugged in

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  This looks to be almost exactly the same answer that was posted 7 years ago, with just different suggested hotkeys for accessing the settings (which may have changed in the last 7 years).  A suggestion that the hotkey might have changed would be more appropriate as a comment, which you can do when you have more reputation, but it doesn't make sense to, for the most part, just duplicate the other answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).