# Grub not showing after upgrading to 14.04 dual boot win8

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I have Ubuntu installed alongside with windows 8 both x64 on hp envy laptop with amd a10. when i upgraded to 14.04 GRUB menu did not show up and windows boots. i had the same problem before when i was first installing Ubuntu and solved it simply by running boot-repair. however this time i tried it but it didn't make any difference.

any suggestion will be helpful.
thanks in advance..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot)

Answer (score 1):

If your system is on UEFI then:

Step1: Switch on windows.

Step2: Open terminal as Administrator.

Step3: Type the command below.

> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} Path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

Comment: This also works if you have updated your ubuntu 14.04 where grub fails to load and windows boots directly.

Answer (score 0):

Using boot-repair, check the flush MBR option.

Another solution could be using Windows Boot Manager rather than Grub. To do so, use easyBCD (https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)