# Dual boot Win8 with Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu installer says "No other OS found"

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-8

I wanted to dual boot Win8 alonside Ubuntu 14.04. However, when I boot from USB stick, the display screen shows that "No other OS found" and hence I cannot install Ubuntu alonside Win8.
The only options I get are to install Ubunbtu (that would result in deletion of Win8) or to create a partition(which seems too complex).
What to do?

Comment: Disable fast startup and secureboot, see http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/

Comment: Done that. I still receive the message "No other OS found". I do not want to partition as this would result in the loss of data.      @bain

Comment: What make/model PC do you have?

Comment: HP 2000. Also I am now done installing Ubuntu by partitioning, as mentioned in the tutorial, but there is no grub screen showing up. It straightaway boots into windows 8. @bain

Comment: ok that is a different issue, see [Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot) and [Windows 8 removes Grub as default boot manager](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager)