# What is the changes to be made in the BIOS settings to show OS options before booting?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

In my laptop I have installed two operating System(OS) Windows 8.1 & Ubuntu in different partitions. When I switch on my lap  it was not showing any options for choosing OS, automatically windows is booting. If I want to boot Ubuntu  then I want to go for  boot option in the bios and I need to choose Ubuntu. I need options to choose the OS before booting how should I do it. can any one help me?
I have also edited the grub file (/etc/default/grub) in Ubuntu and made the  time out to 10 seconds still problems remains.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a couple of weeks ago installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1

See this post - it got me sorted:

First, turn off the Windows 8 Fast Startup feature, as described here:

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html

That feature causes filesystem corruption, which can in turn cause odd boot issues. There's a good chance that this issue caused your problem initially. Disabling Fast Startup might or might not cause GRUB to reappear the next time you reboot.

If that doesn't fix the problem, you should try re-registering GRUB with your firmware's NVRAM. The way to do this that's most reliable is to use bcdedit in Windows. Open an Administrator Command Prompt window and type:

bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

[Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot)

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...