# How can I access GRUB in Windows 8.1

Tags: grub2, windows-8, uefi, 15.04

I have a laptop with Windows 8.1 installed. I installed Ubuntu Gnome 15.04.  I can not access the GRUB to select Ubuntu, the computer just boots straight to windows.

I have found the following articles, and tried everything described with no success:

[Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot)

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

This post as well as the Boot-Repair program told me to try these commands from windows.  After running the commands I'm told that they were successful but the computer still boots into windows.

I have disabled secure boot and fastboot.

Google gave me these instructions:
To access the Boot Menu:
Open the Charm Bar by pressing Windows Key-C.
Click on Settings.
Click on Change PC Settings.
Click on General.
Scroll to the bottom and click on Advanced Startup -> Restart Now.
Click on Use A Device.
Click on Boot Menu.

Although after clicking Use a Device "Boot Menu" is not an option, only my drives.
I can't find the link at the moment, but I was also told to restart into the UEFI menu and change the priority of Boot Options, although, as I expected, only drives are listed under boot options, not partitions or OS Installations.

Does anyone know what I need to do in Windows 8.1 to gain access to my Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Post the URL provided by Boot Repair.

Answer (score 0):

1. Burn Ubuntu Live USB / DVD (You can do it via Unetbootin).
2. Boot the machine in Live Ubuntu environment.
3. Open up terminal and type

   `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair; \`

   `sudo apt-get update; \`

   `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`
4. Once the boot-repair window pops up , click on recommended repair.
5. Reboot.
   This might do the trick

Comment: I did the Boot-Repair already.  It said it was successful, but if i still have trouble to boot into windows and run the command i listed in my question.  This also said successful but I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have a 32-bit version of windows (and 32 bit EFI system) on 64-bit hardware, this is not uncommon. If this is the case,  then I believe you'll need a 32-bit build of grub not the x64 version that ubuntu installs by default.
I use rEFInd boot manager and a 32-bit build of grub to dual boot windows 8 32-bit and Xubuntu 14.04 64 bit. Detailed instructions for both are available on the internet.