# GRUB version 2.02 doesn't show Windows boot manager after dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I had windows 8 , I dual booted windows with ubuntu 14.04 after a while. Now ubuntu is in partition 1 `sda1` and you type this command in Terminal

```
 sudo fdisk -l 
    WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xbbab77f3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   976773167   488386583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

It is clear that partition is not at 63 sector and not multiple of 8. After installing ubuntu, when I boot my system it directly boot up into ubuntu and GNU Grub 2.02 shows only 
Ubuntu 
Advanced options for ubuntu 
system setup

There is no windows boot manager displayed. I am completely beginner . Please help me out and explain clearly

I am also adding the result of sudo parted /dev/sda print

```
    Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
     Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32                 boot
 2      538MB   498GB  498GB   ext4
 3      498GB   500GB  2020MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: Note the message about `fdisk` being useless with GPT disks. Try `sudo parted /dev/sda print` or `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` instead. Edit your question to add one or both of those results.

Comment: @ Rod Smith , I added the result of sudo parted /dev/sda print .

Answer (score 1):

There is no Windows installed on this computer, so there is no way to boot into Windows.

Comment: ***Stop using the computer*** and see [this question and answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/655220/dual-boot-not-working-unable-to-load-windows-on-ubuntu) for further advice.