# The most efficient way to dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I know this seems like a duplicate but this isn’t. I want to know what is the most efficient way to dual boot Ubuntu alongside Windows (not the simpliest way). Let me explain.
Today, I made my dual boot like that. I made a new partition on Windows, I used Rufus to create my bootable USB stick, I booted from it, I installed Ubuntu (root, swap, home) and that’s it. Every time I switch on my computer, GRUB appears and asks me to choose an OS.
The problems are:

- I have 3 unnamed partitions on my disk (root, swap, home)
- My main OS is Windows so I think this is better for me to have the Windows bootmgr, so that I can configure it easier (I use Windows a lot more than Ubuntu)

So, can you tell me how to do this, with websites or whatever, to regroup my partitions in one, and replace GRUB with the Windows bootmgr ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install & Boot ubuntu with windows boot mgr and not grub2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678719/how-to-install-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-boot-mgr-and-not-grub2)

Comment: Windows will not see your Linux partitions. If you want to share data you can add a NTFS data partition, but must have Windows fast start up off as it sets hibernation flag & then Linux NTFS driver will not mount it read/write to protect it from damage. Why not just set Windows as default boot in UEFI and when you want Ubuntu use one time UEFI boot key often f12 or f10 check your manual to choose Ubuntu.

Comment: Title does not seem to match the question. "Most efficient" has no metrics in the question.

Comment: @oldfred i thought about it but I have an HP computer, and when I press f12, it doesn’t show me either Windows or Ubuntu OS

Comment: @user535733 thank you it helped

Comment: @JamesK i’ve already saw this article, but I wasn’t sure it could help me, I’ll try this!

Comment: HP has some different combination of keys. Did you check your manual? Some one posted this: HP - escape + F9 for boot menu, +F10 for bios setup

Comment: @oldfred thank you! ButI have a big problem now... I disabled fast startup, and at boot time, it doesn’t find Windows. How do I boot in Windows. A few days ago, I changed the path of the bootmgr with \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\... I don’t remember the name of the file.... what do I do??

Comment: @oldfred oof. So i put back the initial boot path (that I photographed earlier) in troobleshoot mode. Now it’s ok! I was so scared, but now I can try what was written in the article

Comment: Best to not change /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi files and folders. Even grub finds that to boot Windows. It used to be a work around, but does not really work. There is another work around to boot a drive or fallback boot entry. Many systems show a drive as boot option which is /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. With Windows bootx64.efi is just a copy of Windows boot file. And grub makes it a copy of its shimx64.efi to boot Ubuntu. So choosing hard drive entry in UEFI should boot Ubuntu.

Comment: @oldfred when I press f9, there is ubuntu displayed. However, if I select it, it says that it doesnt find ubuntu bootloader (error screen). Do I have to edit something in bcdedit. I touched a lot of things in bcdedit some months ago when I discovered dual booting... bad idea....

Comment: Not sure where you are at? Some HP work arounds: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred i tried everything to restor windows boot manager but this is impossible.... 1. Set path to the right one (really this time, checked on internet and on other laptops), 2. Set device to the right partition (harddiskVolume1 but maybe this is another one?), 3. bootrec,exe /fixmbr etc...and grub is still showing... if i have to, I will delete Ubuntu but tell me how to get rid of grub pls...

Comment: Need to see Boot-Repair's Summary Report. If you want to dual boot, you have to have grub boot loader. Some just use UEFI as menu to choose which to boot. Some use rEFInd. Many with HP have to change boot order from within UEFI, as efibootmgr does not work. Have you updated UEFI? Many with HP said that helps but does not solve all issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninstall Grub and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)