# Is there something I'm doing wrong in the installation? Ubuntu does not appear, neither does GRUB, but they are all installed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb

I have Windows 10 installed, and because I want to build Android, I require a Linux distro. Ubuntu came to mind.

I made 50GB worth of unallocated space on my HD. Then, I used Universal USB Creator on Windows 10 to create an installation USB, then I booted into it. GRUB showed up, I selected "Install Ubuntu" and I went with the normal installation. Smooth sailing. The installation completed, and Ubuntu prompted me to reboot my computer, which I did.

Motherboard beep. OEM logo. GRUB bootloader, except this is prompting me to install Ubuntu, which I just did. My USB is still plugged in. Whoops. I turn my computer off, unplug the USB, turn it back on, and Windows 10 is booting, without first encountering the GRUB bootloader.

I then combed around Windows 10 for an option that could be messing with GRUB, but Windows 10 sees itself as the only installed OS on my computer. I feel there's something I did wrong.

Can you guys help me boot Ubuntu from my HD? I know it's installed and everything (all previously unallocated space is now occupied according to Windows 10).

Comment: Depending upon your computer, your BIOS may have an option about "which os to boot by-default" having entries ubuntu and windows. Maybe in your case `windows` is selected. If you change it to `ubuntu`, Grub will come and give you the option to boot into either windows or ubuntu.

Comment: I have had a look at my BIOS. It lists Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 as the only installed OSes. Ubuntu is not in this list.

Comment: see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot).