# grub missing (ubuntu dual boot Windows 8.1 )

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

i just recover grub, but it doesn't working ( Dual boot Windows 8.1 and ubuntu 16.04.3) 
bcdedit show this
[bcdedit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfjqq.jpg)  and diskpart this
[diskpart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OprYW.jpg) , i'm sure that ubuntu installed on my hard drive from that
[efi folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVmU1.jpg)

so, how can i show  grub at boot time ?

Comment: What brand/model computer? Can you boot from one time UEFI boot key, often f10 or f12 check your manual. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: acer aspire e15 e5-573G-33TS , i use f12 key

Comment: In your f12 are there unknown entries. Acer has a unique UEFI requirement of setting an UEFI password  (never lose that or reset when done) and enabling "trust" on the .efi boot files from within UEFI. https://askubuntu.com/questions/771455/dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-on-acer-aspire/771749#771749 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
Boot-Repair helped me .... Downloaded as iso and run it as live from usb

Comment: i didn't try boot-repair as iso , but i reinstall it from ubuntu live usb ,   grub not working now :(

Comment: after that my computer reboots into Windows, how i change  BIOS boot order , it only show Windows Boot Loader

Comment: in admin command prompt
 bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
The operation completed successfully.
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
path                    \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
timeout                 20
Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi

Comment: Did you try easybcd? Maybe he can solve problem

Comment: @Amr__r  easybcd can't show me ubuntu partitions

Comment: The Boot-Repair ISO is now pretty old, generally better to just use your Ubuntu live installer and add the ppa to download it into Ubuntu live. The ppa is always more current than a fixed ISO. See option #2 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: boot loader was installed on /dev/sda and when restart computer it boot in windwos , 
how can i load grub ?