# Trying to install Ubuntu but just keeps needing to reinstall it

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, hard-drive

So I have an acer aspire laptop. The original hard drive stopped working and I am using now a 500GB HDD that is in working condition. The laptop is less than a year old so everything else is fine/up to date. I put on Ubuntu on a USB 3.0 16GB stick, and if i dont have it plugged in to my laptop, it gives me an error saying no boot drive avail. but with it plugged in, goes straight to me wanting to install Ubuntu. I follow all steps, sign in to wifi, etc. let it restart and then turn it off again, unplug the usb stick, and then i get the same error where it cant find a boot drive. I have my hard drive as the boot drives number 1, and this will be the third time trying to install it. It gives me the option to just use Ubuntu without installing, but then I have to reenter my wifi passwords and wait for it to fully load each time. How do I solve this?

Comment: Acer has a unique requirement of setting an UEFI password & enabling "trust" from within UEFI on ubuntu/grub's .efi boot files. https://askubuntu.com/questions/771455/dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-on-acer-aspire/771749#771749 &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238 Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot  Also make sure UEFI is latest from Acer, do  not downgrade as some older threads mention.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible secure boot or UEFI is enabled.  If this laptop is that new look in the BIOS menu for secure boot, UEFI, and disable it.  I've had this happen before on ubuntu installs with this annoying "feature" enabled.