# how can I boot up ubunt on my Acer laptop?

Tags: boot, acer

Ubuntu perfectly worked on my Acer Aspire E 17 laptop, not until I tried to install and partition Kali Linux in a USB drive. After I finished doing the partitioning, I tried to turn on my laptop and it only turns on and shows Acer logo and then Ubuntu won't boot. Please, I need a help in making my laptop boot back to normal.  I will be very grateful for any help. Thanks guys

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Did Acer lose its "trust" setting? https://askubuntu.com/questions/771455/dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-on-acer-aspire/771749#771749

Comment: thanks for this information but the issue is that my laptop does not boot at all. it only shows the make "Acer" and then the next thing is a dark screen with  a "dash" blicking on the top left of the screen

Comment: Are you not even able to get into UEFI? Have you tried a "cold" boot. Or turn all power off, remove batter if laptop, and hold power switch for 10 sec or so to drain any left over power. Then boot and press correct key to get into UEFI. Or this? Ubuntu 17.10 "corrupting" BIOS - many LENOVO laptops models Intel SPI & kernel issue Also some Acer
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147

Comment: Hi, I use Acer Aspire E 17 and I just bought it a month ago. The truth is that the battery is not removable( I have tried to turn the power off several times and I have tried to boot from BIOS. I can boot it from BIOS. but the issue is that when I changed it to boot from HDD and not from FLASH DRIVE. it didn't show any sign. I had to change the BIOS back to boot from flash drive. The issue is that after the display of "Acer" on startup, it turns to a black screen with a blinking dash at the top left of the screen

Comment: Then you may be booting, but have graphical issues. What video card/chip do you have? Still need Summary Report from Boot-Repair. See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it