# I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS alongside Windows 10, but now I can't find it or boot to it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I finished installing Ubuntu 16.04.3 alongside Windows 10. I made sure to turn off Hibernate and Fast Shutdown on Windows, made my BIOS UEFI and unsecured. When I boot I still can't find Ubuntu. I also tried going to the live version on my USB and running the boot repair with no help. Ubuntu made a new partition in my hard drive the size it said it was going to, but I have no idea how to access this. I can get into Windows and only Windows. I keep seeing that Grub Loader or something should let me choose which OS to load, but I haven't seen anything even close to that. I can't even choose Ubuntu from the BIOS menu when I hit F12. I have no idea what to do and all of the articles I have read haven't helped me at all. A little more information is that I am running on an Acer Aspire Laptop. I look forward to any help anyone can provide.

Comment: All Acer have a unique requirement of setting UEFI supervisory password and enabling "trust" on the Ubuntu/grub .efi boot files. https://askubuntu.com/questions/771455/dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-on-acer-aspire/771749#771749 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003

Comment: Thanks oldfred, my answer was in here in changing a setting in my BIOS. I got it installed

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Go to your boot loader (by pressing F2 or whatever your computer understands) and find something like this:
   [See Image. Source: https://www.eightforums.com/installation-setup/53912-windows-boot-order-problem.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBzgp.png)
2. If you find Ubuntu or grub there, just change the order of them to get Ubuntu on top preference. Carefully read instructions there and 'Exit Saving Changes'.
3. Restart your PC.

This time you should be able to see the grub. If not, I would recommend doing a clean install of Ubuntu again by properly configuring the partitions yourself. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are using a SSD and the SATA option is "RAID ON". First check what SATA option is by going in the settings of your BIOS. If it's "RAID ON", don't change it immediately, first set windows to boot in safe mode (Because windows can't boot in normal mode through AHCI):

Login into Windows 10, and set up Safe Mode: "Change advanced Startup Options" -> "Restart Now" -> "Troubleshoot" > "Advanced options" > "Startup Settings" > "Restart"

Boot laptop and press F-X (Whatever your manufacturer's key is) -> BIOS Setup

System Configuration -> SATA Operation

Change SATA Operation from "RAID On" to "AHCI"

Apply and Exit. This will reboot the laptop, and provide several boot options

Choose "4. Safe Mode"

"Start" -> "Windows System" -> "Control Panel" -> "Device Manager". Check that the "IDE ATA/ATAPI controller" is "Intel(R) 100 Series/C230 Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller"

Reboot normally. This should boot into the regular Window 10

If you reboot and go into the BIOS, SATA Operation should still be AHCI

Taken from [install Ubuntu on XPS 15](https://github.com/rcasero/doc/wiki/Ubuntu-linux-on-Dell-XPS-15-(9560)).