# Dual boot Ubuntu 16.04.3 & Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I have just bought an Acer Aspire laptop with Windows 10 installed. Wife wants Windows but I prefer Linux. Had dual boot with Win 7 before and it worked well. I know it did not go well with Vista.

Can I just install Ubuntu alongside Win 10 and let it provide the boot loader as it did before? It was really simple with Win 7.

Comment: After install, Acer has unique requirment of setting "trust" from within UEFI. https://askubuntu.com/questions/771455/dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-on-acer-aspire/771749#771749 and 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238Which is: https://askubuntu.com/questions/597213/bootable-device-not-found-after-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-uefi

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

I have practically the same setup you have (Acer Aspire, Win 10 Pre. installed) and both systems work fine.

I used a USB-Stick and the instructions from here:
https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/

Note: I did however deactivate the fast boot, as explained here:
https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/

You can see both guides are quite similar, i cant not confirm how important the fast boot deactivation is, but it might be important

Have fun

Comment: I have exactly this setup on the refurbished Thinkpad T430 I bought a few months ago.  Came with Win10 occupying the entire HDD -- used Live USB to resize the Windows partition and install Ubuntu, GRUB starts either one as requested.

Comment: One reason for deactivating fast boot is that it prevents the accessing of files in Windows partition from Ubuntu (though, this is an optional feature). There could be more reasons.  [link](http://linuxbsdos.com/2016/06/05/how-to-access-your-windows-10-files-from-linux-on-a-dual-boot-system/)