# EFI Partition not detected after ubuntu install

Tags: 16.04, uefi, acer

I have finished installing ubuntu on my SSD. Before Installation, I set up the disk partition to gpt with GParted. During Installation, I have done the following partion:

/dev/sda1 EFI 500 MB

/dev/sda2 ext4 120 GB

But, after reboot, the EFI partition is not detected in my UEFI BIOS (InsydeH20 running on a ACER ASPIRE7). UEFI and Secure Boot are enabled.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean not detected? does it boot? what error do you get?

Comment: No, the EFI partition (where grub is) is not detected by firmware.

Comment: It must be FAT32, I believe. Is it?

Comment: Yes i did FAT32 formating with boot and esp flags.

Comment: @MichaelBay -- yes it must be FAT. FAT32 is most commonly used. Is ACER one that requires marking "trusted" before it will boot it?

Comment: I tried to set it up as trusted in UEFI, but it's not listed in HDD0/efi so I cannot.

Comment: Some systems require the ESP to be partition 2 as they have a factory recovery in partition 1.

Comment: the path would be HDD0/EFI/ubuntu/ . if shimx64.efi is not there then grub didn't get installed

Comment: There is something really strange. After installation, in the live usb mode, I try to mount the efi partion:

sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

But I see no files in /mnt . Is this normal ?

Comment: Acer once installed has an unique requirement of setting "trust", but you must have done an UEFI install to have /EFI/ubuntu in ESP - efi system partition. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot
 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/771455/dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-on-acer-aspire/771749#771749 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/908854/installed-ubuntu-17-04-and-now-cant-boot-at-all-failed-to-open-efi-boot-grubx/909238#909238

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to use grub-restore to make my efi partition visible again by the firmware. No clue what happened.