# Can I add Ubuntu in Windows Boot Manager using Windows 10?

Tags: grub2

I'd like to boot into Ubuntu using the Windows Boot Manager on Windows 10 using UEFI. Can I do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do not use EasyBCD with UEFI. Some use it with BIOS, but not recommended as then grub is installed in an unreliable mode. You can add an entry to BCD. http://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot

Comment: @AndroidDev The post you described is *Legacy/BIOS only* and will break Windows' UEFI bootloader.

Comment: @oldfred - That question is tagged with `uefi`... so the answer is wrong and should be deleted?

Comment: With UEFI you just add a BCD entry, do not use EasyBCD other than I think you can use it to ad the entry directly as BCD editor, but you can use Windows own editor. But not to use grub4dos to chain load to grub in a partition as with UEFI grub is only in the ESP - efi system partition.