# How can I add Ubuntu to the Windows EFI bootloader?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I have dual boot with Windows 10 in UEFI mode. I don't want to use GRUB (but I don't want to delete grub). I want to use Windows boot manager. I set Windows boot manager as first boot device in BIOS and I want to add new entry to windows 10 boot loader to boot into Linux.

EasyBCD can't do this because I am in UEFI mode.

I installed GRUB in EFI partition.

How to do this?

Comment: should probably ask on a windows forums if you are not using grub/ubuntu software.

Comment: Boot-Repair also suggests this as one alternative for UEFI systems that do not work with grub/shim directly. http://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot

Answer (score 0):

Simply said: You can't.

- GRUB 2 is compatible with Windows.
- The Windows boot loader is only compatible with... well... Windows!