# Installation alongside Windows 10 on Lenovo Yoga 500 - no GRUB menu, Windows just boots

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, lenovo

I'm a Linux newbie and just installed Ubuntu on my [Lenovo Yoga 500](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/yoga-series/yoga-500-14acl?linkTrack=Caps%3ABody_BrowseProduct&searchType=0&keyWordSearch=) from a Live USB drive. The installation was successful, however, when I restarted the computer after installing Ubuntu, the GRUB window didn't show. I was following along a small tutorial I found on YouTube, and everything worked perfectly until that point. Ubuntu even said the installation was successful, but the GRUB window doesn't show and Windows 10 boots up.

I have tried changing the boot mode from Legacy to UEFI and disabling Secure Boot, but it didn't work. Tried disabling fast start up, but that didn't work either. Ubuntu doesn't show up in the boot priority section of the boot setup either. What else can I try?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot)

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? You should never boot in CSM/Legacy/BIOS mode if Windows is UEFI boot. Boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI mode and run this: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. At that time I overcome it by changing the OS boot manager in the bios. You just enter bios> system configuration> enter os boot manager> select ubuntu press <kbd>f10</kbd> (button to save, it might be different) then press again.

Comment: This won't work. Ubuntu does not show up in the boot menu. It's why i can't select Ubuntu.