# Problem with reinstall Grub on dual-boot

Tags: grub2

i have some problems with grub, when i start my computer. I have black screen, so i cant choose with system i want to start, then ubuntu is starting. I dont want to change in bios priority of booting from UEFI to Legancy. When i do it last time all was fine with windows, but when i change it again to UEFI, i got window with info "ubuntu boot failed"
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/f7jRCTnDCs/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot)

Comment: You cannot mix BIOS & UEFI boot modes if you want to use grub to boot. Once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch. Windows is in BIOS boot mode & Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. Since UEFI hardware & Microsoft has required UEFI for Windows since 2012, probably better to reinstall Windows. But that is a huge hassle. You can use Boot-Repair and convert Ubuntu to BIOS boot, but only use advanced mode and install grub to sdb (Ubuntu) drive, and keep Windows boot loader in sda drive. Grub only boots working Windows, so you may need to directly boot Windows from UEFI/BIOS menu.