# Acer Swift 3 booting to Windows 10 instead of Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, windows-10

I've recently tried installing Ubuntu 18.04 from a hard drive onto my Acer Swift 3 laptop. I'm new to Linux so chose to do the automatic install. Everything seems to be running fine except when I try to boot up it automatically goes to windows 10. I've reinstalled with quick start disabled and still no luck.

When I do efibootmgr ubuntu doesnt show up on the list, but windows does.

I tried doing sudo grub-install /dev/sda but it just said "grub install error failed to get canonical path /cow". I mounted the drive and it fixed this but it couldnt find i386-pc.

boot-repair gave this output http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XXzmHWrvGB

The BIOS also says the boot mode is legacy, if that helps.

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot) and [Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/371559)