# GRUB menu doesn't show

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

Recently I had made clean install of windows 10 and after that dual boot with ubuntu 20.10. When I turn my PC on, it automatically starts Windows without showing grub menu. Some time before I had dual boot, just with Ubuntu 20.04 instead .10 and everything worked fine.

I have tried with commenting GRUB_STYLE = hidden, and with changing that hidden to menu, but that didn't worked. This was done in the `/etc/default/grub` file

Should I change something in UEFI?

I can boot to ubuntu only if I press `ESC` on startup, and when advanced options for UEFI shows, go for `F9` to see *Boot device options*. There I have option for booting up the Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot)

Comment: Those with HP have said UEFI update and then only changing boot order from within UEFI works. Most UEFI accept changes by efibootmgr which is what grub also uses to install & change boot order.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Windows likes to override any bootloader with its own when installed. You have installed Ubuntu after Windows, but I would still try to solve the problem as if it happened for this reason.

First answer to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68581/how-can-i-prevent-windows-from-overwriting-grub-when-using-a-dual-boot-machine) question seems to outline how to get it back pretty well. Basically, boot from a Linux LiveCD/flash drive and reinstall grub.