# Ubuntu grub menu not showing fix

Tags: grub2

I'm facing this problem with my laptop. Ubuntu is installed alongside Windows 10 and when I press "Enter" at startup it's not showing the Ubuntu Grub menu! I'm new to this OS and noob!  Can anyone help me?

Also, I tried to add a new entry with EasyBcd, and not working! Please help!

**Edit:** Well i found a solution for this problem! So

• first open your BIOS and Go to System Configuration > BOOT Options > Os Boot Manager
• Then select ubuntu by pressing arrow keys
• Then press F5 or F6 (Just look for bottom of your pc screen and look for **"Change Value"** )
• Now save & exit

Comment: Yeah it worked Thanks bro!

Comment: This answer is the one that worked and is referred to in the last paragraph of the question: https://askubuntu.com/a/1170553/