# Windows 10 and ubuntu dual boot without option to choose after turn on computer

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I wanted to create windows 10 and ubuntu classic dual boot. That one when you will power on your computer you can choose which one do you want to run. And I tried it by multiple tutorials when finally I did something. I have installed ubuntu. And whe I will click in windows on settings, updates... and restart now and choose use device. I have there ubuntu and if I run it it will after asking me to run other things actually run ubuntu and it is working completely fine. But if I want to go to ubuntu I must start windows and do all this which is just annoying. Do you have any ideas how can I create from this the classical dual boot menu? I didn't try anything, because I have no idea what I don't want to reinstall ubuntu from scratch, because it is working and I could have damage it even more.

Comment: Did you install WSL or Linux inside Windows? From Windows app store? If you want full install of Ubuntu you need to download installer ISO, use tools to extract ISO to flash drive, & boot installer ISO to install. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview  & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb  & https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot)

Comment: Thank you everyone for comments. I did this command: bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi and it is working now. But not perfectly it will only give me only 10 seconds to choose and if I won't it will just choose ubuntu. Windows is not named windows but windows boot manager.

Comment: @user3 If you want to change/increase the time to more than 10 seconds, After logging in go to a terminal and edit the grub entry using `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`. If you go there you can see `GRUB_TIMEOUT` set to 10. Change it as you wish. Do not mess with other options unless you know what you're doing. To set Windows as default visit this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader and refer the accepted answer.