# Cannot access my second internal HDD 1TB on latest Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive

I just installed Latest Ubuntu x64 from USB. All was OK. Installed on my Win 8.1 with option "replace your current Windows with Ubuntu". (Not dual boot with Windows,)
My question: How to get in to my HDD to store files? P.S. I am new to Ubuntu.
Here is some info:

```
mrk@M:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001b5e0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   968419327   484208640   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       968421374   976771071     4174849    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       968421376   976771071     4174848   82  Linux swap / Solaris

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00008000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sdg: 4043 MB, 4043308544 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 491 cylinders, total 7897087 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004fb8d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdg1   *        2048     7897086     3947519+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)



mrk@M:~$ sudo parted -l

Model: ATA ST500DM002-1BD14 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  496GB  496GB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      496GB   500GB  4275MB  extended
 5      496GB   500GB  4275MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: ATA ST31000520AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      33.6MB  21.5GB  21.5GB               primary  raid
 2      21.5GB  1000GB  979GB   ntfs         primary  hidden, msftdata


Model: Generic USB Flash Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdg: 4043MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  4043MB  4042MB  primary  fat32        boot, lba


mrk@M:~$
```

---

I really do not understand yet what it means. Just curious about:

```
   21.5GB  1000GB  979GB   ntfs         primary  hidden, msftdata
```

I have very important files on my 1TB HDD, but I am able to format it. No function to mount or whatsoever to do with that HDD. I want to save it if there is a possibility of doing that.

Please help.

Comment: Does `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb2 /mnt` give errors? If the don't give errors, does the `/mnt` folder show you your files? According to the answers [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/371487/is-it-safe-to-format-msftres-msftdata-and-hidden-partitions), the paritition flags are okay.

Comment: Thank you MUCH :) I am able to use my 1TB now. I did what you told to do: sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb2 /mnt and it was mounted with no errors. Thank you much, i can access all my files now. I am NEW on Ubuntu, so please dont hate me for disturbing your time with such small problems as was mine.

Comment: A 1TB drive not mounting is not a small problem. I'll update my answer with better instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an internal HDD, we can add an entry to `/etc/fstab` to make Ubuntu mount it on boot every time. First, pick a directory you want to mount it on (like `/home/marius/internal`, where `marius` is your username. Make sure the directory exists (make a new one if you need to). Then, do:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
/dev/sdb1 /home/marius/internal ntfs-3g rw,exec,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -u),umask=022 0 0
EOF
```

This will add an entry to `/etc/fstab` giving you proper read/write permissions.
Then, do:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
sudo mount /dev/sdb1
```

The first command will undo the previous mount, then the second will mount it with the new settings.

---

If it is a new hard disk, you can format it afresh, and start using it. Open the Disks program, select your new hard disk from the right hand pane, click on the gear icon in the top right corner, and choose *Format*. 
[image: Disks screenshot]

Use the default option (both GPT and MBR work fine). Once it creates a new partition table, click on the `+`, choose a size. For the type, if you wish to use it on Windows as well, select "Compatible with most systems (NTFS)" instead of the default (`ext4`).  Give a nice label. Click on the play icon to mount it. (Or on the corresponding icon in the file browser.)

I'm sorry I can't give you more information about the hidden RAID part.

Comment: I am sorry for my question. I did not mentioned that i have very important files on my 1TB HDD, but i am able to format it. No function to mount or what so ever to do with that HDD. I want to save it if there is possibility to do that.

Comment: @MariusRaudys In which case I am very off-target with my answer. All right, let's look into mounting it manually.