# GParted Unknown Partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, suspend, gparted

I recently opened up GParted to partition some space and I noticed an unknown partition being listen. I don't know whether this is why my computer has booting/waking from suspend really slowly but if someone could give me advice on whether to ignore it or directions on how to fix it, that'd be great.

[image]

Comment: look here: http://askubuntu.com/a/371605/72216

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That unknown partition is the **windows system reserved** created by the Windows 7 or 8 when doing their respective installation. It is approximately 128 MB for system reserved stuff, which includes part of the installation process and booting. You do not want to delete that partition except if you want to remove Windows completely.

The flag shown in the image (msftres or Microsoft Reserved) can be found in [Is it safe to format msftres, msftdata and hidden partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371487/is-it-safe-to-format-msftres-msftdata-and-hidden-partitions)

If you go into Windows you will not see this partition on it since it is marked with a special flag that tells the Disk manager (In Windows) not to see it). With Ubuntu using any partition manager can see it. I recommend not moving the partition, resizing it, deleting it or doing any changes to it unless you want to have some Windows issues.